# How to add data as Password protected field in SQLITE Database?

Tags: iphone, ios4, sqlite, passwords

I am new to iPhone programming,need some Help,

I am using SQLITE Database In my App,

My question is,

When user insert the text in Database it's add as password protected like,

If Text = **Hello**,  In SQLITE Database that field is stored as **XXXXX**,

& when retrieve that data from database it can be show as Text,"**Hello**".

Is that Possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement an encryption algorithm, encrypt your passwd and then save it in to the db.

Edit:
Take a look to this blog post [How to encrypt/decrypt using AES 256](http://www.sixtemia.com/journal/2010/06/30/how-to-encryptdecrypt-using-aes/)

Comment: Thanks for Answer, wan't to know which algorithms we are using for encrypt & decrypt the data, I do googling but can't get the Appropriate answer,If you provide some link or code for Algorithm ,Really  It should be Appreciated.

Comment: Link's broken, apparently.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. I'd recommend you using encryptor to encrypt the password(obviously) and store it encrypted in the database. And when a user logs in, encrypt the password that he typed and compare it to the one in the database. That way you will decrease the potential possibility of a password leak(but if encrypted password will be obtained by some hacker/cracker/@$$h0l3 he won't have much possibilities with it, except for trying to decrypt or brute-force).

Hope it helps